# Divide points into sets of maximum distance

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a list of GPS points...but what am I asking for could also work for any X,Y coordinates.

In my use-case, I want to assign points in sets. Each point can belong in only one set and each set has a condition that distance between any of two points in the set is not greater than some constant...that means, all points of the set fit a circle of a specific diameter.

For a list of points, I want to find best (or at least some) arrangement in which there is minimal number of sets.

There will be sets with just a single point because other points around are already in different sets or simply because there are no points around (distance between them is greater than in the condition of the set)...what I want to avoid is inefficient set assignment where e.g. instead of finding ideal 2 sets, each having 30 points, I find 5 sets, one with 1 point, second with 40 points, etc...

All I'am capable of is a brute-force solution, compute all distances, build all posible set arrangements, sort them by number of sets and pick one with the least number of sets.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is NP-complete. What you try to solve is the max-clique problem combined with a set cover problem.

Your problem can be represented as a Graph G=(V,E), where the vertices are your coordinates and the edges the connections in distances. This graph can be made in O(n^2) time. Then you filter out all edges with a distance greater then your constant giving the graph G'.

With the the remaining graph G' you want to find all cliques (effectively solving max-clique). A clique is a fully connected set of vertices. Name this list of cliques S.

Now finding a minimal set of elements of S that cover all vertices V is the set cover problem.

Both the set cover problem and the max clique are NP complete. And therefore finding an optimal solution would take exponential time. You could look at approximation algorithms for these two problems.

Comment: Once you have `G'`, the rest I'm fairly sure is solving the [clique cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem).

Comment: Yes, @Nuclearman, you are right. In fact due to the nature of NPC problems, it is any problem, and finding another NPC problem in a NPC problem is not strange since every NPC problem is reducible to any other NPC problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I do that every now and then too.